# Will <noscript> hide the rest of the static content to Google crawlers?

Tags: indexing, seo, noscript, google-crawlers

This should be an easy one for someone:

Will the `<noscript>` element cause the HTML page to serve only the content within the `<noscript>` tag itself to google crawlers and hide all the rest of my static content causing it so not to be indexed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The crawlers will see *all* your content, both within the `<noscript>` element and everywhere else.

Crawlers behave a lot like browsers with JavaScript turned off - they see all the static content plus the `<noscript>` content, but not anything JavaScript-dependent.

Answer (score 3):

The whole HTML file is served in response to a GET request.  Google should honour robots.txt and not spider directories marked with that.